# Cloud of points curve fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, points

I have a 2D cloud of points, i imported them into matlab and i want to have a smoothing spline function that passes through them. I tried with the "curve fitting" app and the "smoothing spline" option but in the extremes the function seems to not follow much the cloud and anyway in the middle of the cloud does not pass trough the points but goes up or down the points. I tried "basic fitting" option after i plotted the cloud but no improvements as you can see:
[image]

The idea of what i wanted is this:[image]

Of course i modified the image with Gimp (i am using linux) and the red line is a hand made one...so not so smooth as it would be. Note i have magnified the image.
I was asking to myself if it was possible to have a variable grade fitting along all the cloud.
Anyway i don't know how to do it and any suggestion is appreciated.
[image]

The "smoothing spline" (in the "curve fitting tool") seems to be more equal to an interpolation than to a spline
[image]

Comment: Please show the exact code you used

Comment: May i obtain a better result just increasing the order of the polynomial equation? If yes how can i do it?

Comment: You probably need to increase the number of the polynomial, or the number of spline pieces, or both. I don't know how you can do it. Maybe someone will, specially if you show your code

Comment: @Luis Mendo,I just plotted the points. The data is a matrix where the first column is the x coordinate and the second is the y

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You're not using any code, but rather the graphical tool, right? Does that let you use splines rather than a single polynomial?

Comment: yeah, you are right. In the last image i uploaded i used the "tools->basic fitting" option. Anyway i used the app "curve fitting" too, another graphical tool, so no code.

Comment: i added another image where i used the "curve fitting tool"

Comment: Have a look at nonparamteric regression or kernal regression. Here are some file exchang entries that might work for you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19195-kernel-smoothing-regression http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19564-local-linear-kernel-regression

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `spline` instead of the graphical tool. For example:

```
x = 1:100; % x-axis values for data
y = conv(randn(1,100),ones(1,10),'same'); % example smooth random data

xx = 1:.1:100; % x-axis values for plotting the spline
yy = spline(x,y,xx);
plot(x,y,'.',xx,yy)
```

[image: Resulting figure]

See the doc of [`spline`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) for more information.

Comment: But spline won't work for that hand drawn image. It doesn't go through all the points but smooths. Maybe you could interpolate a spline and then smooth with a low pass filter afterwards?

Comment: @Dan, how can i do it? could you please make me an example? i have no idea of what a low pass filter is.

Comment: @merlinuxxx one example of a lpf is just a rolling average. Try something like `conv(YourSpline, ones(n,1))`. play around with different sizes of `n`. Odd numbers are conventional.

Comment: @Dan I think `spline` does pass through all the data points. At least in my tests it does. For example, try my answer with `y=randn(1,100);`. That's totally uncorrelated values, and it passes through all of them

Comment: @LuisMendo yes exactly, I'm saying that I think the OP does NOT want it to pass through all the points.

Comment: @Dan Oh, I get it. Yes, that's a problem with `spline`. Maybe the lowpass filtering should be done on the original data, rather than on the spline.